# trouble installing os_sys package recieving os_sys has invalid wheel error

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm running this command to install os_sys package:

> pip3 install os_sys

but receiving this error:

> ERROR: os-sys has an invalid wheel, could not read
> 'os_sys-1.9.3.dist-info/WHEEL' file: KeyError("There is no item named
> 'os_sys-1.9.3.dist-info/WHEEL' in the archive")

I already installed Wheel.
Thank you for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into same issue. Actually, this package is already included in Python.
So, just use

```
import os
import sys
```

in your py script and this should work.

Comment: if you dont have os-sys then import will not work. The question is we are facing issue while installing os-sys package.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still not working for you, try to make sure that you have installed only one version of Python, I ran into the same issue, and any os method I tried to use was not working for me at all.

What I have done: I deinstalled all the other versions, and then I made only one clean installation, also removed the Path entries related to the deinstalled older versions. Then it finally worked!

Comment: the issue does not seem to be related to python